# Custom User Model in admin on Django 1.5

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm using a custom user model `myapp.MyUser` in a Django 1.5 app. I updated my settings as documentation says to do, `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "myapp.MyUser"`. As MyUser extends AbstractUser, I created the admin with this code:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

admin.site.register(get_user_model(), UserAdmin)
```

And it works fine, except the creation form. When I try to create a new user, the following exception is raised:

```
DatabaseError at /admin/core/user/add/
(1146, "Table 'mydatabase.auth_user' doesn't exist")
```

The full traceback can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/lucassmagal/5715264).

Digging out Django's source code it looks like `UserCreationForm` - which is used by UserAdmin - references django's built-in `auth.User` [directly](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L89), instead of use `get_user_model`.

Can it be the problem? Why everything references `myapp.MyUser`, including admin's auth and the change form, except the creation?

Comment: Did you run `syncdb`?

Comment: Yep @girasquid, myapp_myuser was created, but auth_user won't, as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, the `UserCreationForm` references `auth.User` directly. The Django docs on [custom users and built in auth forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms) state that you must rewrite it for any custom user model.

> **UserCreationForm**
>
> Depends on the User model. *Must be re-written for any custom user model.*

There is a related ticket [Ticket 20086](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20086), which was initially closed as invalid, because the user creation form is working as documented.

There is a [full example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example) on the same page, which shows you how to rewrite the forms and register a custom user model in the admin.

Comment: I see, but I thought it was only for AbstractBaseUser. My fault, I didn't read that [part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-the-built-in-auth-forms).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind to store your custom model in a table called `auth_user` you can simply set this in `Meta` and this solves `auth_user table doesn't exist`. All you need is:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):

    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
        db_table = 'auth_user'
```